# Branch specified by RE cannot work in Gerrit Trigger plugin of Jenkins

Tags: regex, jenkins, gerrit

In order to monitor changes uploaded to Gerrit in Jenkins, I used the Gerrit Trigger Plugin to accomplish it. And by setting project and branch information, I can monitor the a specific branch within a specific project.


However, I have an unusual demand. For example:

1. Project A has three branch named master, dev/feature-one and dev/feature-two.

2. Now, I need to monitor changes from these branches except dev/feature-two.

So I used RegExp type to specify the branch pattern with value ^(?!(dev/feature-two)).* to filter out the dev/feature-two branch, however, this didn't work and the Gerrit Trigger Plugin can capture changes under all the three branches.


But if I used value ".*" to monitor all these branches to do a testing of RegExp, it works this time.


So I confused by the RegExp checking of Gerrit Trigger Plugin, and I doubt that if there is no support for the lookahead regular expression.


If you are familiar about the Gerrit Trigger Plugin, could you offer me some help.

Thank you advance.